# Какой виджет используется для этой выдвижной панели?

Tags: android, виджет

Всем привет! Хотелось бы узнать, какой виджет используется для фильтров в VK App на Android. Заранее благодарю за ответ!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для всего этого можно сделать кастомное вью, и скорее всего в ВК так и сделано, а можно воспользоваться какими нибудь либами.

Рецепт прост:

1. Сама панель может представлять из себя какой нить **Expandable Layout**. На гитхабе можете легко найти библиотеку, вот одна из них собственно так и называется - [ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout)
2. Для галочки справа так же можно воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой, например этой - [Android-ExpandIcon](https://github.com/zagum/Android-ExpandIcon)
3. Остается только связать две эти view для синхронизации состояния.